# vscode intellisense python module from import problem

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HvDW.png)

from PyQt5.Qtwidgets import {QApplication}
the bracket section, intellisense don't show import modules of PyQt5.Qtwidgets.
how can i do?

Comment: Welcome to SO :) Please explain the problem properly.

Comment: i solved to use jedi thanks to comment